# Installing requests package breaks anaconda installation

Tags: python, python-requests, anaconda, conda

I'm having an issue where when I install the requests package on a fresh anaconda install (onto an environment), it breaks my anaconda in a way where I cannot download any further packages due to an HTTP error.

The process I've gone through a number of times now is:

1. Uninstall anaconda (using anaconda-clean and add/remove programs)
2. Re-install anaconda
3. Run `conda update conda` on my base environment
4. Run `conda create -n auckland-index python=3.7` to create a new environment
5. I install pandas with `conda install pandas` to make sure I can download packages in the new environment
6. I then run `conda install requests` to install requests, which downloads and installs successfully
7. Then when I try to install any other packages I get the below CondaHTTPError across both base and new environments

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

I have tried installing requests before pandas and after other packages, but I get an CondaHTTPError always after installing requests.

I have tried the following from other stack questions to fix (of which none work):

- Set `ssl_verify: false` in .condarc
- Copy both libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll to the anaconda3/DLLs folder

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why installing requests is causing this issue, as I'm downloading it through the conda install command. This isn't a network issue either as the downloading and installing of packages was working before requests was installed. Once I have installed requests I cannot download any more packages for any environment.

Has anyone had this issue or know of a fix? Is this a bug?

EDIT: from each environment I have run `conda list requests` and `python -c "import requests; print(requests.__spec__)"`, with the results below.

**Base**

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0

ModuleSpec(name='requests', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000284138E7FC8>, origin='%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages\\requests\\__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages\\requests'])
```

**auckland-index**

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0

ModuleSpec(name='requests', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000284138E7FC8>, origin='%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages\\requests\\__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages\\requests'])
```

EDIT 2: Adding path variables from base environment

```
['', '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\python37.zip',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\open-data-api',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\Auckland-Index-Update',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\DLLs',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index',
 '%USERPROFILE%',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages\\locket-0.2.1-py3.7.egg',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\auckland-index\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\.ipython',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python37.zip',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Comment: maybe this may help https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046#issuecomment-477187514 . Also try to access `http://` url. If error will not appear, the problem is ssl libraries

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @rzlvmp, I have gone through the steps and installed openssl, however, still getting the CondaHTTPError.

Comment: @merv, see post, have edited it and added the output from each of those commands. Does this look like the cause of the issue? I noticed they both point to the same module, which would explain why the base is having the issue too.

Comment: @Trizzy yes, that is likely the issue. The question is, Why is the **base** env loading modules from the **auckland-index** env? Envs are normally isolated; leakage can be triggered by a non-empty `PYTHONPATH`. You can see where the **base** env searches by running `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` from activated **base** environment.

Comment: Specifically, I suspect the failure is due to **base** Python loading the **auckland-index**'s `requests` module and it somehow has different non-Python dependency requirements than the earlier build, which are not satisfied by **base** environment. While this wouldn't solve the underlying issue of the env leakage, it may work to force the **base** env to update `requests` with: `conda update -n base --offline requests`.

Comment: Thanks @merv, I've added the path variables above. With updating requests, I tried the command you suggested and initially got `Updating requests is constricted by anaconda -> requires requests==2.22.0=py37_0` then it printed `# All requested packages already installed.` 

I could try a fresh install again and try updating requests from the base environment first, or, installing requests v2.22.0 in my other environment?

Comment: Honestly, if you're open to reinstalling my general recommendation is [Mambaforge **base** environment](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge). However, it would be nice to solve this problem - but if you're eager to get moving, I'd certainly understand.

Comment: Sorry to keep requesting stuff, but: could you also add `echo %PATH%` and `echo %PYTHONPATH%`, when **base** is activated? Indeed, the `sys.path` is problematic, so you need to figure out why the `sites` module is searching there.

Comment: There was a PYTHONPATH environment variable that was causing this issue, not sure how it was still there as I had deleted this on an earlier re-installation but it seemed to have come back. Once I deleted this environment variable it seems to be working without error across all anaconda environments. Was a bit of a silly error on my behalf, thanks @merv for all the help troubleshooting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was caused by PYTHONPATH windows environment variable, once this was deleted problem was solved. Thanks to @merv for help getting there.